# dplyr replace by position in R

Tags: r, dplyr

The value of the third row of `mtcars$mpg` is `22.8`.

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars$mpg[[3]]
```

I go ahead and replace this `22.8` with the value `5,555` as shown below. It works but not at the third row as I command my computer to do! Instead the value shows up at the 22nd row of the `mtcars$mpg` column.

```
mtreplace <- mtcars %>% mutate(mpg = replace(mpg, mpg[[3]], 5555))
mtreplace
mtreplace$mpg[[3]]
mtreplace$mpg[[22]]
```

How do I get this change to occur at precisely the third row of `mtcars$mpg`? And what went wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code should be

```
mtcars %>% mutate(mpg = replace(mpg, 3, 5555))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think dplyr is probably overkill, and may not be the best tool for this issue. This works fine:

```
mtcars[3, "mpg"] <- 5555
```

Also worth bearing in mind that for a numeric vector, you should use single [. The [[ is for lists when you want to get an element and not a range of elements (ie you don’t want another list).

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
     mutate(mpg = case_when(row_number() == 3 ~ 5555, TRUE ~ mpg))
```